# Whose face is in the jack-in-the-box?

Tags: botanicula

Is it a dev? Dev's friend? Who?

[image: jack-in-the-box]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The faces that pop up in the jack-in-the-box are those of the crew at Amanita Design, the studio behind the game.

[image]

That particular face is that of Jaromír Plachý, one of their animators/graphic designers.